# UISearchBar Got a Huge Blurry Magnifying Glass Icon

Tags: ios, ios7, ios5, ios6

I run across the very weird problem on the `UISearchBar` Magnifying Glass icon display.
I have the following code on my `viewDidLoad:` method, however, the searchBar I got is so weird (it's huge and blurry).

Greatly appreciated if anyone knows how to fix it (My intention is to have the smaller magnifying glass displayer inside the search bar)?

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```

[image]

I also tried to do this on the storyboard, looks like it produces the same result...it`s so weird...

Comment: You can still post a link of your screenshot?

Comment: thanks picture has been uploaded